# WebStorm 2016.3.2 "Missing import statement"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, libraries, systemjs

So I have WebStorm javascript project powered by `Systemjs and JSPM`. Little annoying thing is that Webstorm can't see global `System` object, so marks it as **Missing import statement** in the **config.js** file.

I followed a tip:

```
When using libraries that define their own global symbols outside 
their visible JavaScript code (e.g. describe() in Mocha), it is   
recommended that you add the corresponding TypeScript type definition 
file as a JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | 
JavaScript | Libraries.
```

And added `system.js` file from **jspm_packages** to the Javascript libraries in the Webstorm settings of my project.

[image]

**But it didn't help. Any idea what I am missing?**

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

1. Select the mocha library in the list
2. Click the "Download ..." button on the right side.
3. Search for mocha
4. Click the "Download and Install" button.

[Download Library window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEmlx.png)

Comment: The same thing worked for me when attempting to use Webix.  For webix, however, you must point to custom library and supply the directory manually.